# Ways on getting the location of your friend's/contact Android Phone using your own Android phone

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I know how to code a program which get my location (longitude, and latitude) using my own android phone. But how can my program get the location of my friends android phone? Assuming that he had also installed my locator program. I know this is possible because there are lots of like this in google play. (I already know how to use text but I dont know how to do it with wifi or internet.)

Please check this link. I want to create an application like this. Thanks. Please help me. Thank you very much.

"[Sample Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zoemob.familylocator)

Comment: Both of the answers are good but i could not check all of them. So Ill just check the answer with a low rep socre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

If you really want to track your family a central server containing logs might be the best idea. That way, even if they disappear and turn their phone off you will still have the log with their latest positions.

You could make a background service that reacts to locationchanges with

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);

The server just stores all these logs. (Make a simple php page that accepts these messages and then stores them in a database but make sure others can't spoof the message.)

This might be useful: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

Comment: I really don't want to use central server because I need to pay for it and I want this application to be free as much as possible.

Comment: You could turn your computer into a server with a dynamic dns with a service like noip.com. This way you own the server and the sensitive data. The downsides are that 1) you don't want your computer to be on all the time and 2) your ISP may try and block things like this (choosing a port >1024 will often fix this).

Comment: Another option you could do (but this is a bit of a dirty one) is using a service like GMail. At GMail you have gigabytes of webspace meant for e-mails. You could setup an account and have the logs be sent as e-mails to the GMail account. The user of the program (your friend) would never know the logs are sent in an e-mail format because that all happens in the background.
This way you also don't need to send the friends location periodically but you could make the phone receive push messages from GMail. You just 'catch' the notifications for the specific accound and respond with coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Continuously listening to location updates in your app is a costly operation which drains the battery and also consumes user's internet(3G data).

I have a couple of solutions and you could choose one of them.

Use a broadcast receiver that reads text messages. You could send a text message to the phone whenever needed, and using `BroadcastReceiver`, you could probably update the location in the server.

The other way is to use `GCM` to send push messages whenever needed, and on receiving push message, mobile would update its latest location.

In both the cases, I suggest you to use `GooglePlayServicesClient` to read location as it is very optimised.

Comment: GCM is interesting.. Should i use XMPP? for google messaging? Is it possible to not use a webserver? I mean the android device will store the messages from the other device from google cloud?

Comment: If you don't want to use a server then, go with the other solution, Broadcast Receiver and responder.